# Post Privately to Facebook Application Wall Page

Tags: facebook, privacy, posting

When you publish a post to your application's wall, is it possible to set the privacy of it?

As per the "privacy" option mentioned here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Privacy seems to be ignored when I try it (and I am doing it as the application admin).  It doesn't seem like this case is included in the paragraph below, but perhaps this is the reason (from the same page):

> Note: This privacy setting only applies to posts to the current or specified user's own Wall. Facebook ignores this setting for targeted Wall posts (when the user is writing on the Wall of a friend, Page, event, group connected to the user). Consistent with behavior on Facebook, all targeted posts are viewable by anyone who can see the target's Wall.

Comment: post the code to see how are you trying to add privacy options and to be able to detect any issues

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is post to the applications wall page using a Page access token.  See the "Page login" part of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/.